# Task Properties are not updated in state machine workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, state-machine

I have created state machine workflow using visual studio 2013. Now, I want to update task properties when user click on ok button on task list item.

Code block of workflow events:

```
// Invoked event of Manager
    private void onTaskChangedByManager_Invoked(object sender, ExternalDataEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            onTaskChangedByManager_AfterProperties = onTaskChangedByManager.AfterProperties;
            onTaskChangedByManager_BeforeProperties = onTaskChangedByManager.BeforeProperties;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    // called on task change event of Manager
    private void ManagerApprovalProcess(object sender, ConditionalEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (onTaskChangedByManager_AfterProperties.PercentComplete == 1.0)
            {
                onTaskChangedByManager_AfterProperties.Description = "abc";
                e.Result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Result = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

In code block I have updated description property of task list. It will not generate any error but value is not updated.

It is executed perfectly but task properties are not updated.

My workflow :
[image]